# How to create base layout file in django

Tags: python, django

In `templates` folder I have 2 HTML files, `index.html` and `add.html` file, I want to create one layout file and want to add a header and a footer into it, and in middle content I want to override my 2 files into that layout file, can anyone please help me with this?

Here are my 2 html files:

**index.html:**

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}">

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Page Title</th>
        <th>Update Date</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    {% if pagelist %}
        {% for page in pagelist %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ page.title }}</td>
                <td>{{ page.updated_date }}</td>
                <td><a href="{% url 'crud:update' page.id %}">Edit</a></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else  %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">Np Pages are available</td>
            </tr>
    {% endif %}
</table>
```

**add.html:**

```
{% load static %}



<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}">

<form method="post" action="{% url 'crud:add' %}" name="page_form" id="page_form">
    <input type="text" name="title" value="{{ title }}">
    <input type="text" name="permialink" value="{{ permialink }}">
    <input type="text" name="updated_date" value="">
    <input type="text" name="bodytext" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="pages_id" value="{{ page_id }}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Did you read the docs and the tutorial which show you exactly how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow [this tutorial](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/template_extending/) and can have for example:

**base.html**

```
<body>
    <div class="page-header">
        <!-- your header here -->
    </div>
    <div class="content container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page-footer">
        <!-- your footer here -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Then the `index.html` can extend `base.html` as follows :

**index.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Page Title</th>
        <th>Update Date</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    {% if pagelist %}
        {% for page in pagelist %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ page.title }}</td>
                <td>{{ page.updated_date }}</td>
                <td><a href="{% url 'crud:update' page.id %}">Edit</a></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else  %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">Np Pages are available</td>
            </tr>
    {% endif %}
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

**note** you can add more blocks which can be overriden in `base.html` template to render `js` and `css` inside head and so on..).

It is easy once you get a grasp of `blocks of code` and the fact that **they can be overriden in child templates**

do similar for `add.html` template